# numba: faster implmentation of series sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I need to calculate the following series sum for 10K points in my setting. So I use the numba to accelerate my computation

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def kernel(x, y, t, m, n):
  return (1 + (-1)**(m+1))*(1 - np.cos(0.5*n*pi))*np.sin(0.5*m*pi*x)*np.sin(0.5*n*pi*y)*np.exp(-(pi**2)*(m**2 + n**2)*t/36)/(m*n)

@jit(nopython=True)
def Series_Sum(x, y, t, m, n):
  res = 0
  for i in np.linspace(1, m, m):
    for j in np.linspace(1, n, n):
      res += kernel(x, y, t, i, j)
      # print(res)
  return 200*res/(pi**2)

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 101)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.concatenate((X.flatten()[:, None], Y.flatten()[:, None]), axis=1)

m, n = 100, 100
exact =[Series_Sum(i[0], i[1], 0, m, n) for i in Z]
```

However, the result are all 'nan'.

For example

```
Series_Sum(0.3,1.5,1,100,2) # returns nan
```

if i do the following

```
res = 0
for i in np.linspace(1, m, m):
    for j in np.linspace(1, n, n):
        res += kernel(x, y, t, i, j)
```

The result is fine.

Also, if I remove the '@jit' decrator, the result is reasonable, but, it takes hours to calculate the result.

Is there any better way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the error. It's when you do your power on `(-1)**(m+1)` you need to do a floor on `m+1`.

You can do:

```
    A = (1 + np.power(-1, int(m+1)))
    B = (1 - np.cos(0.5*n*np.pi))
    C = np.sin(0.5*m*np.pi*x)
    D = np.sin(0.5*n*np.pi*y)
    E = np.exp(-(np.pi**2)*(m**2 + n**2)*t/36)
    F = (m*n)
    return A*B*C*D*E/F
```

I hope my answer correspond to your question

Comment: But i don't know why when you do in the iterative way you don't obtain a `nan`